# MFMailComposeViewController file attachment name with foreign characters

Tags: iphone

I have searched far and wide and was surprised nothing like this came up.
I am trying to send an audio file email attachment (using MFMailComposeViewController) that has Chinese/Kanji characters in the file name. The weird thing is when I use a particular character in the file name, it becomes a long strand of weird characters when I receive the email.

With a file name like "平成23年.m4a", the name of the attachment when I receive the email becomes something like "平成23�"/%1B%28B8%1B%24B7n%1B%28B25%1B%24..."  It is the character "年" that is causing this. If I delete that character, everything is fine. There might be another Chinese/Kanji character out there that might cause the same problem, but I have no idea how to even begin to fix this...I've been pulling my hair out so hopefully someone can help me with this...

Also a similar problem is that with certain email providers (works fine for gmail, yahoo, but not for something like gmboy.com), if I have Japanese characters in the file name, they fail to show up and gets replaced by an underscore sign. (e.g. Testテスト.m4a turns into  Test_.m4a) I feel that this may be related to the problem above.

Here's my code...

```
/* Set up the mail compose view and put in the body/attachment */
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[self itemsToSend] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [dict objectForKey:@"exportFileAddress"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *fileName = @"平成23年.m4a";
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"audio/m4a" fileName:fileName];


[mailComposer setMessageBody:@"Test email" isHTML:YES];

/* Set default subject */
[mailComposer setSubject:@"Email subject"];

mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;        
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
```

The file attachment name will show up just fine when the MFMailComposeViewController view comes up, but somehow during the sending process, the name got screwed up.

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Oh I didn't notice your comment Akshay. Thanks for the input. Like I said below I just tried with the default iOS app and same problem occurs. So yeah, it's not just me using the API incorrectly...

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you enter the same filename text in the subject field (either programmatically, or via the composer UI)?

If that works, you should use your email program to look at the headers for that email and see how the word was encoded.  Better yet, send an email with the attached file and filename from some other email program and investigate the headers in the email it sends.

My best guess is you need to encode your string using [rfc2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047), which describes how non ASCII characters can be embedded in multi-part email headers.  Too bad this isn't being done for you!

Comment: Hey TomSwift thanks for the reply! Foreign characters in the subject field works fine, but I've encountered one email provider where it doesn't show. So it's still the same problem I'm guessing.

How do I check through my email program how the word was encoded?

And thanks I will check out the link!

Comment: I have just tried using the default iOS voice memo program to send to email a voice memo. I named the memo to send the exact same name, and guess what, SAME PROBLEM! 

I tried sending from another email program the same file name and it displayed fine, which is why this must be more of a problem with the MFMailComposeViewController class itself rather than the email provider right?

Comment: You can look at the headers of an email in gmail, for example, by selecting "Show original" when reading a message.  It sounds like none of the iOS email clients are encoding attached file(names) using rfc2047, so the big question is whether you can pass the filename pre-encoded to MFMailComposeViewController.  A good test would be to send yourself this file using your email program, copy/paste the encoded header into your NSString filename, and send that.

Answer (score 0):

'audio/m4a' isn't a valid mimeType. Are you looking for 'audio/mp4'?